# Check if a single character is a whitespace?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to check if a single character is a whitespace?

I know how to check this through a regex.

But I am not sure if this is the best way if I only have a single character.

Isn't there a better way (concerning performance) for checking if it's a whitespace?

If I do something like this. I would miss white spaces like tabs I guess?

```
if (ch == ' ') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I use ((c <= 32 && c >= 0) || c == 127).  Gets all the whitespace and control characters in ascii.

Answer (score 51):

If you only want to test for certain whitespace characters, do so manually, otherwise, use a regular expression, ie

```
/\s/.test(ch)
```

Keep in mind that different browsers match different characters, eg in Firefox, `\s` is equivalent to ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters))

```
[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]
```

whereas in Internet Explorer, it should be ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28VS.85%29.aspx#sectionToggle2))

```
[ \f\n\r\t\v]
```

The MSDN page actually forgot the space ;)

Comment: @kangax: nice to know; at least for IE, the documentation is consistent with the actual result (missing space aside)

Comment: note that both linked pages have been updated since then - the MSDN one now includes the space, and the Mozilla one includes additional Unicode whitespace characters

Answer (score 29):

The regex approach is a solid way to go.  But here's what I do when I'm lazy and forget the proper regex syntax:

```
str.trim() === '' ? alert('just whitespace') : alert('not whitespace');
```

Comment: And this could be faster as well.

Answer (score 13):

I have referenced the set of whitespace characters matched by PHP's [trim](http://php.net/trim) function without shame (minus the null byte, I have no idea how well browsers will handle that).

```
if (' \t\n\r\v'.indexOf(ch) > -1) {
    // ...
}
```

This looks like premature optimization to me though.

Comment: Looks like this is a tiny bit faster than using RegExp: http://jsperf.com/whitespace-character

Answer (score 8):

this covers spaces, tabs and newlines:

```
if ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t') || (ch == '\n'))
```

this should be best for performance. put the whitespace character you expect to be most likely, first.

if performance is really important, probably best to consider the bigger picture than individual operations like this...

Comment: there are also '\r' and '\r\n', but I would say it's better to use regex than use an if with 5 conditions. It would be faster in my opinion.

Comment: well, it's always best to profile in cases like this. depending on how likely each character is, the short-circuiting of `||` might actually make it faster.

Comment: This would do function isWhiteSpace(ch){ return " \t\n\r\v".indexOf(ch) != -1; }

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.
It's clear to me that it's better to use a RegExp...
Better safe then sorry ;)

Comment: Using five manual comparisons is actually faster than any option: http://jsperf.com/whitespace-character/5

Answer (score 6):

While it's not entirely correct, I use this pragmatic and fast solution:

```
if (ch.charCodeAt(0) <= 32) {...
```

Comment: I think it's fine. It's the same in Unicode and ASCII. If the ch is undefined then undefined is not less than or equal to 32. You can also just do if (ch <= ' ').

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this](https://jsbench.me/b1ku0bggvi/1) benchmark, it appears the following method would be most performant:

***For Performance:***

```js
function isWhitespace(c) {
    return c === ' '
        || c === '\n'
        || c === '\t'
        || c === '\r'
        || c === '\f'
        || c === '\v'
        || c === '\u00a0'
        || c === '\u1680'
        || c === '\u2000'
        || c === '\u200a'
        || c === '\u2028'
        || c === '\u2029'
        || c === '\u202f'
        || c === '\u205f'
        || c === '\u3000'
        || c === '\ufeff'
}
```

There are, no doubt, some cases were you might want this level of performance (I'm working on a markdown converter and am trying to squeeze out as much performance as possible). However, in most cases, this level of optimization is unnecessary. In such cases, I would recommend something like this:

***For Simplicity:***

```js
const whitespaceRe = /\s/
function isWhitespace(c) {
  return whitespaceRe.test(c)
}
```

This is more readable, and less likely to have a typo and, therefore, less likely to have a bug.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb but shouldn't those be `or`s not `and`s?

Answer (score 3):

@jake 's answer above -- using the `trim()` method -- is the best option. If you have a single character ch as a hex number:

```
String.fromCharCode(ch).trim() === ""
```

will return true for all whitespace characters.

Unfortunately, comparison like `<=32` will not catch all whitespace characters. For example; `0xA0` (non-breaking space) is treated as whitespace in Javascript and yet it is > 32. Searching using `indexOf()` with a string like `"\t\n\r\v"` will be incorrect for the same reason.

Here's a short JS snippet that illustrates this: https://repl.it/@saleemsiddiqui/JavascriptStringTrim

Answer (score 1):

```
var testWhite = (x) {
    var white = new RegExp(/^\s$/);
    return white.test(x.charAt(0));
};
```

This small function will allow you to enter a string of variable length as an argument and it will report "true" if the first character is white space or "false" otherwise.  You can easily put any character from a string into the function using the indexOf or charAt methods.  Examples:

```
var str = "Today I wish I were not in Afghanistan.";
testWhite(str.charAt(9));  // This would test character "i" and would return false.
testWhite(str.charAt(str.indexOf("I") + 1));  // This would return true.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}
```

This will work

or 
you can also use this indexOf():

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following code removes the whitespace from a string in JavaScript ✅**

```
var string = "white space";

function removeWhiteSpaceFromString(str) {
console.log("Before removing the whitespace: " + str);

var chars = str.split("");
var text = "";

for (ch of chars) 
if (ch != " ") {
  text += ch;
 }
}
console.log(" After removing the whitespace: " + text);
}


removeWhiteSpaceFromString(string);
```

Answer (score -3):

how about this one :
((1L << ch) & ((ch - 64) >> 31) & 0x100002600L) != 0L

Comment: Sorry, but that is not javascript. That's C. And, this is a question about javascript.