# Check if first character of string is digit or whitespace with regex or alternative

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a given string's first character is a word character/not a digit or white-space and return a boolean.

I'm trying to use regex for this. What I have is:

```
function isFirstIndexCharacter(str){

   var regex = RegExp('w')
   return regex.test(str[0]);
}
```

I always get false no matter what my input is. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: `var regex = /^\w/;`

Comment: That's just checking that the character `w` is present. For a word character use`^\w` and for a word character (without digit) use `^[^\W\d]`. You should note that `\w` also includes `_` so if that's not what you're looking for, use `^[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496826/check-if-a-single-character-is-a-whitespace). It doesn't include numbers, but numbers is the easy part...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this -

```js
function isFirstIndexCharacter(str){
  return /^\w/.test(str[0]);
}
```